# Communicate between two unrelated components

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

How do you handle communication between components with no common parent in react-native ?

What's the best way to communicate between two unrelated components ?

I did some research and the most recommended way seems to be using context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html.

Comment: Context API works with a common parent and not with unrelated components.Check redux for such a usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiples way to handle a global state, one of them is the new React Context API, but one of the most famous is [redux](https://redux.js.org/), written by Dan Abramov, who works at Facebook, inspired by flux, an old facebook library to manage global state. There is also Mobx and many others, I suggest you take a look at each one and see what fits you best, it's hard to tell you without knowing your problem. Feel free to ask any other question about one of them